# What shall I do with the 2nd partition?

Tags: installation, partitioning

When installing Ubuntu, I have divided my hard disk into two partitions.(based on experience with Windows)

The main is 10GB and the other one is 65 GB huge. Now I am running out of space (about 4 GB left on main disk).

After googling, I understood that there is no chance to change the default installation directory to another partition.

Could you suggest me what to do, because I have unused space on the whole 2nd partition (65 GB)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to shrink the 2nd partition and extend the 1st one.

1. **Backup your data**
2. Burn a Live CD
3. Boot from the Live CD
4. Install gparted `sudo apt-get install gparted`
5. Start gparted `sudo gparted`
6. Shrink your 2nd partition.
7. Expand your 1st partition.
8. Eject the disk, restart and boot your normal Ubuntu

I hope this helped you,

Daniel

Comment: If you are not planning on using the second partition at all, you could just delete it in step 5 and expand the first partition to cover the whole disc.

Comment: **@Daniel**, are you sure that it isn't dangerous? Won't he lose data?

Comment: @B. Roland You need backups before extending/shrinking partitions first, of course. Thanks for the reminder, added this information to my answer :)

Comment: You shouldn't have to install `gparted`... I thought it came on the LiveCD.

Comment: @George It's not on every Live CD. Sometimes I have to install gparted first, sometimes not.

Comment: @Daniel0108 what do you mean every live cd?  It is on every Ubuntu live cd, but obviously there are probably other distributions's that don't have it on theirs.  You also can just run it from the administration menu.

Comment: @psusi I'd have to test this now, but it was a Debian based distro.

Comment: Live CD is a disk, that I have used to install Ubuntu?

Comment: Can I backup the whole main partition? And then can I restore all settings or I have to customize the system after shrinking and expanding partitions?

Comment: @URLArenzo Yes, the Live CD is the disk you used for installing ubuntu. Yes, go to your home folder with nautilus and press `Ctrl+H`. Now select all files and copy&paste them to your backup disk.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to resizing, you can move your /home directory to the other partition.  Programs will still be using the limited space on /, but your personal files and media and such can be on the other partition, which should free up some more space for /.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving